# Can a GCP persistent disk be be mounted/claimed by multiple pods in ReadWriteMany mode?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I've got a persistent disk (GCP), that I'm hoping to be able to allow read write access to multiple pods.

Is this possible? Here are my two configs:

**pVolume.yaml**

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "PersistentVolume"
metadata:
  name: "pv0001" 
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: "10Gi" 
  accessModes:
    - "ReadWriteMany"
  gcePersistentDisk: 
    fsType: "ext4" 
    pdName: "wordpress-disk"
```

**pVolumeClaim.yaml**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

With the above config, I see the following error on my pods:

```
FailedMount Failed to attach volume "pv0001" on node "xyz" with: googleapi: Error 400: The disk resource 'abc' is already being used by 'xyz'
```

This occurs with the replica count set to 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a GCP persistent disk in ReadWrite mode on different nodes this is not possible :(

It is possible however:

- Have both replicas scheduled on the **same node**. In that case both of them can mount the same persistent disk ReadWrite
- Use it in **ReadOnly mode**, on any number of nodes
- Use a **different kind of PV**, like [gluster](https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes) or nfs that supports this kind of use